# Bootswatch/Bootstrap CSS/Theme Breaks Page in IE7 & IE8

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootswatch

I am trying to use http://bootswatch.com/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css in my page. I've just tried using http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css as well. However it seems to break the page as follows. The navbar at the top loses its links and the main content goes full width. I am basing it on this example http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/

[image: Bad Version]

However things start to get better when I use bootstrap.min.css from https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v3.0.0/bootstrap-3.0.0-dist.zip

[image: Good Version]

Any ideas what's happening at all? I've just compared http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css against my local copy and it's exactly the same! So I downloaded it, saved in and referenced it and now it works.

**[UPDATE]** It *seems* that IE8 is playing ball but still no luck with IE7 even using https://github.com/coliff/bootstrap-ie7

[image: IE7 Broken]

Answer (score 1):

IE8 and below don't support the responsive media queries that Bootstrap uses. Have you included https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond (Respond.js) to enable media query support? The bootstrap website states [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers) that you need to include it for IE8 or anything under it